# Android 9 Chrome Intent not opening the application

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, android-9.0-pie

I dig a lot around Google Chrome Intents in order to open application from browser, and find out that there is a strange issue with Chrome Intents on Android 9 specifically.

Here is my example intent (I changed some of the data because of NDA):

```
intent://record/#Intent;scheme=myapp;package=com.myapp;S.host=wss.myapp.com;S.port=8443;S.token=1234-abcd-5678-efgh;S.browser_fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloperx.myapp dev.com/recorder;end
```

This is the "href" attribute in browser for the link, and it works great for all Android OS versions except Android 9.

Any thoughts? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have found the rootcause or solution for this issue?